# How to send array in hashmap in android?

Tags: android, hashmap, retrofit

**i want to send below data in row form is like :**

```
  {
  "sender_id":"A1234567",
  "sender_name":"abc",
  "division_name":["test D1","test D2"]
  }
```

**how can i send devision name in hashmap ?**

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("sender_id", edSenderId.getText().toString().trim());
    map.put("sender_name", edSenderName.getText().toString().trim());
    map.put("division_name","..." );
```

Comment: It depends on how server side you have managed. You can convert it to string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send array like below code;

```
  int childCount = move_st_list.getChildCount();

 ArrayList<String> student_ids = new ArrayList<>();

  // Here I m fetching all students ids from RecyclerView's adapter class....

    for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
    {
        MyAdapter.ViewHolder childHolder = (MyAdapter.ViewHolder) move_st_list.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i);

        student_ids.add(studentAttendancePojo.getStudentSerchList().get(i).getiStudentId());
    }

    JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(student_ids);
```

Then pass it in map;

```
    map.put("division_name",jsArray);
```